# sorting and filtering together not working properly

Tags: sorting, jsf, primefaces, datatable, filtering

Using sortBy and filterBy together in a column of a dataTable,it just doesn't work properly, 'cause when I first try to sort the column, all of my list disappears and shows nothing at all.
when I then try to filter in that moment, it works and when I start again to filter or sort, it works.
So it's only at the very first time, by sorting , that it gives me problems.
what shall I do more? 
I use primefaces code as it is shown in showCases. I use a filteredList, empty, for filteredvalue in datatable (which is a private variable with its getter and setter) and simply use sortBy and filterBy on columns, the last of which uses a filteringMode of type "contains".

Comment: Can you add your code of what you've tried so far?

Comment: code in [mcve] format